# C# Get location file

Tags: c#

*Hello.I have problem with my code :*

```
 string path = THIS LOCATION(Program must get this folder location) + "Test.txt"        
    if(File.Exists(path))
    {
    }
    Else
    {
    }
```

*I do not know what to write in a string to retrieve the program folder location in which it is located.*

Comment: what kind of app is it? Winforms? WPF? Console? DLL? Website?

Answer (score 5):

you could use `Application.StartupPath` if this is a Winforms app.

you can also use `Application.ExecutablePath` but take a look here for more understanding about this... http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

you can also use, sometimes, `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

you can also use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

If you are wanting to look in the directory the application that kickstarted the process, then replace the above with:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location
```

if you are using a web app - slightly different story there.

Again, depends on the type of app you are using. Web/Winforms/Console all differ slightly in this respect